# Macro to pick file in folder with current date in other than standard format

Tags: date, excel, vba

Could you please let me know how to revise the below code so that it opens it automatically?

```
 Range("A1:AK1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Y:\DentalConsumables\Company\DMC\DMC - Planning & Materials\Build Plan DTW Reports\DataWHSreports\2015-03-26_DWHS_PEN EU Fixed.xlsx" _
        , UpdateLinks:=0, Notify:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the date part changes, you can give this a try:

**Edit1:** Closing the opened file

```
Dim curDate As String, Fname As String
curDate = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") ' returns the current date in specified format
Dim wb As Workbook ' add a variable to pass your workbook object

Fname = "Y:\DentalConsumables\Company\DMC\DMC - Planning & Materials\" _
        & "Build Plan DTW Reports\DataWHSreports\" & curDate 
        & "_DWHS_PEN EU Fixed.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Fname, UpdateLinks:=False, Notify:=False)

' ~~> Other cool stuff goes here

wb.Close False ' Close the opened workbook; False indicates to not save changes
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked great. Another question: could you please explain why the first "&" was necessary: Planning & Materials\" _ & "Build Plan DTW Reports\DataWHSreports\" & curDate. Also, how would I code it if I want to close the opened file? Thanks again

Comment: @Jason It is not really necessary. I just did it in two lines instead of one to make it readable on my browser (no scroll bars). As for your follow-up,  see my edit.

Comment: Thanks to you, I am getting a hang of it. Closing worked flawlessly. Could you please help me close this final file where I used "like" to open it. Thanks again.

Comment: also, how would I have posted the above code as a code, like my original post?

Comment: @Jason You can post another question for that. Also you might want to [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thank you for that link. Very helpful. Got rid of all the activesheets, activerange,etc. Only remaining ones are the activeworkbooks. That is next. Thanks again.